# How to fix problem 'Update plugin to start this course' for jetbrain's Learn Rust course?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I am trying to get jetbrain's rust course working but I have this problem:
[image]

I have installed the rust toolchain and the rust plugin. When I click update on the problem this comes up:

[image]

so I press ok and nothing happens. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I am using Intellij community with the education version and I am on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/EDC-740/Cannot-start-Learn-Rust-Course

Please try the course again and it should work now.

> The problem here is that the course published from nightly plugin version where a new version of the archive format was introduced (15).
> As a result, stable plugin complains that it doesn't support the new format version but at this moment there isn't new stable version with new format support

> An archive generated with the stable EduTools is uploaded, the corrupted version is hidden. It should be ok now.